# convert date time to utc format

Tags: javascript, react-native, date, momentjs

I have to convert local date and time to utc format.
Therefore if I have date as 2021-08-11 (YYYY-MM-DD) and time as 2:40 PM, then slot date time should be `2021-08-11T09:10:00.000Z`.
I have tried multiple things, but failed

```
const dateTimeInUTC = moment(
  `${formattedDate} ${formatTime}`,
  'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
).toISOString();
```

above code resulted me => `2021-08-10T21:10:00.000Z` (which is +5:30 more)

Also, tried following

```
const formatted = formattedDate + " " +formatTime (2021-08-11 02:40 PM)
const result = new Date(formatted).toISOString();
```

this gave me

> Range error :Invalid Date

However, this works as expected in console, but gives error in mobile.

Answer (score 1):

I tested it now, convert  `-` to `/` in date format then it will work fine in react native both on browser console and mobile. [for more info you can check that link](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/782)

```
var isoDateString = new Date('2021/08/11 12:00 pm').toISOString();
console.log(isoDateString);
```

[image]

If you want to use your date format (date witn `-`) then you to add `T` instead of space   and the time should be on 24 hour scale
like

```
var isoDateString = new Date('2021-08-11T13:00').toISOString();
```

this solution will also work for you.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try that

```
 var isoDateString = new Date('2021-08-11 2:40').toISOString();
console.log(isoDateString);
```

Comment: Didn't worked. It  is the same thing which I did and gave me the RangeError: Invalid Date

Answer (score 0):

If you want to covert current System Time to UTC then Do :

```js
const dateTimeInUTC = new Date().toUTCString();
console.log(dateTimeInUTC);
```

Or if you want convert any specific Date-Time to UTC then Do :

```js
const dateTimeInUTC = new Date("October 13, 2000 00:45:00").toUTCString();
console.log(dateTimeInUTC);
```

Comment: None of them worked. Giving me incorrect result

Comment: what's the question?